# FileSystemException: Cannot copy file to 'storage/emulated/0/Download/', path = '/data/user/0/com.xx.x/f' (OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno

Tags: android, flutter, download, path-provider

I'm trying to save my file into Downloads folder but in android `path_provider` package does not support `getDownloadsDirectory` so I decided to save manually in `/storage/emulated/0/Download` but it shows me this error message:

> Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot copy file to 'storage/emulated/0/Download/filename', path = '/data/user/0/com.xx.x/files/filename.pdf' (OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1)

my permission for storage is already granted using `Permission.storage.request()` and I've also added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
       tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
```

but still doesn't work. Anyone willing to help?

Comment: Android version of used device?

Comment: `Cannot copy file to` Well what exactly is 'cannot'? Reading the original file or creating a new one?

Comment: @blackapps it happened on Android 12 but it's fixed now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that for rename/copy, the OS refused character like : in the name.
It was my issue.
It's ok on Android 8, but not 10 or 13.

regards

Comment: hello, it seems that for rename/copy, the OS refused character like : in the name.
It was my issue.
It's ok on Android 8, but not 10 or 13.

regards

Comment: yes you're right sir they refused : in the name because i was using date and time to make a unique file name so I ended up changed it to (1) (2)

Answer (score 0):

yes the same,
I Cannot rename or copy
(OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1)
on Android 11 and on 13

it's well on Android 8

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to be a naming convention matter where they do not allow date time as name I think " : " for the time is the cause. Therefore I've changed the naming duplicate files as (1) (2) and it's working now.